# What am I doing wrong with ThreadExecutionState?

Tags: c#, .net, sleep-mode

I'm trying to prevent my laptop from going to sleep when I'm opening a program, I've set the sleep mode to 1 minute and am running a timer set to tick every 50 seconds.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{       

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer1.Start();            
    }

    [FlagsAttribute]
    public enum EXECUTION_STATE : uint
    {
        ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED = 0x00000040,
        ES_CONTINUOUS = 0x80000000,
        ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED = 0x00000002,
        ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED = 0x00000001
        // Legacy flag, should not be used.
        // ES_USER_PRESENT = 0x00000004
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern EXECUTION_STATE SetThreadExecutionState(EXECUTION_STATE esFlags);

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetThreadExecutionState(EXECUTION_STATE.ES_CONTINUOUS | EXECUTION_STATE.ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED);            
    }
}
```

When running this program it waits for 50 seconds, should fire the function and prevent it from sleeping, yet it goes to sleep ~50 seconds after starting the program. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1) Did you check the *response*? If it's 0 it means the call failed. 2) Which timer are you using? Only `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` runs on the UI thread. All [other timers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks) run on other threads. If you use System.Timers.Timer or System.Threading.Timer you're modifying the wrong trhead

Comment: You only asked for the monitor to stay powered on, not the system.  You only need a timer when you don't use ES_CONTINUOUS.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm using the System.Windows.Forms.Timer, I'm not sure on how to get a response back from this function though.

Comment: Just save the response in a variable (`var newState=SetThreadExecutionState(...);`) and check it with an `if` statement. If it *doesn't* match what you specified, log it at least. Try debugging the application and check the return value

Comment: I tried, it gave me an "ES_CONTINUOUS" as result, this shouldn't be happening right? I want a "ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED" (to get sleepmode to go away?)

Comment: Any resolution after all this time?